# For an instance field which is an array value, how does one handle additional tasks whenever the array mutates by e.g. pushing into or splicing it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, setter, es6-proxy

The `set` accessor does not take place whenever one does mutate the `Crumbs` class property value by e.g `push`ing into it.

I'm trying to create a class property via `set` syntax which I expect to handle an additional `sessionStorage` task. But every time, I'm going to push an item into the array, the `set` accessor does not take place.

The code I came up with so far is as follows ...

```
class Environment {
  constructor() {
    this.Crumbs = [];
  }
  set Crumbs(value) {
    // debugger;
    sessionStorage.setItem('_crumbs', JSON.stringify(value));
  }
  get Crumbs() {
    // debugger;
    let result = [];

    if (sessionStorage.getItem('_crumbs') !== null) {

      result = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('_crumbs'));
    } else {
      sessionStorage.setItem('_crumbs', JSON.stringify([]));
    }
    return result;
  }           
}
let env = new Environment();

let _metricId = 6;
let _concept = 'Back orders';

let _crumb = {
  MetricId: _metricId,
  Concept: _concept,
};
env.Crumbs.push(_crumb);
```

Comment: `push` won't activate the setter. You have to actually set it like `env.Crumbs = ...`

Comment: @PeterSeliger Sincerely I use the first response from the comments, I appreciate your response and your time.

Comment: @JosueBarrios ... How do you handle or even prevent a user (from) operating the `Crumbs` array via mutating array methods like e.g. `push`, `pop`, `unshift`, `shift` and `splice`?

Answer (score 1):

None of the mutating array methods will ever activate the OP's setter. This only happens for direct assignments to `Crumbs`.

But since the OP wants to go with the least effort of handling array changes by any array operation, the OP needs to expose a [proxyfied](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) array as an `Environment` instance's `crumbs` property. The proxy's [`handler` configuration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy#description) has to implement just the [`set` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/set), and moreover needs to specifically handle just the change to the proxy's `length` property, where one would keep the stored `crumbs` value up to date by storing the local/internal `crumbList` mirror.

```js
class Environment {
  constructor() {
    // - always "up to date" mirror of the `this.crumbs` proxy object.
    // - initialized either from `sessionStorage` or as empty array.
    const crumbList =
      JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('crumbs') ?? null) ?? [];

    this.crumbs = new Proxy(crumbList, {
      set(obj, prop, value) {
        // debugger;
        // console.log({ obj, prop, value });

        // proceed with `set`.
        const result = Reflect.set(...arguments);

        if (prop === 'length') {
          // - immediately put most recent `crumbList`
          //   mirror into `sessionStorage`.
          sessionStorage.setItem('crumbs', JSON.stringify(crumbList));
        }
        return result;
      }
    });
    // - since one does access the `this.crumbs` proxy for any
    //   (mutating) array operation, one might think about a
    //   custom `valueOf` implementation which returns a shallow
    //   copy of the proxy object's up to date mirror state.
    Object.defineProperty(this.crumbs, 'valueOf', {
      value: function valueOf () {
        return [...crumbList];
      },
    });
  }
}
const env = new Environment;

const metricId = 6;
const concept = 'Back orders';

const crumb = { metricId, concept };

env.crumbs.push(crumb);

env.crumbs.push('foo');
env.crumbs.push('bar');

env.crumbs.length = 5;

env.crumbs.push('baz');
env.crumbs.push('biz');

env.crumbs.length = 9;

console.log('... after initial `push` operations and `crumbs.length` changes ...');
console.log({ "current value": env.crumbs });

env.crumbs.shift();
env.crumbs.pop();
env.crumbs.pop();

console.log('... after `shift` and `pop` operations ...');
console.log({ "current value": env.crumbs });

env.crumbs.splice(1, 3);

console.log('... after a final `splice` operation ...');
console.log({ "current valueOf()": env.crumbs.valueOf() });

console.log({ "currently stored JSON": sessionStorage.getItem('crumbs') });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
  // mock for the SO specific stack snippet
  // due to the policies and environment are
  // not allowing an original storage access.
  const sessionStorage = (function () {

    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map
    const storage = new Map;

    function key(int) {
      return [
        ...storage.keys()
      ][parseInt(int, 10)];
    }

    function setItem(key, value) {
      return storage.set(String(key), String(value));
    }
    function getItem(key) {
      return storage.get(String(key));
    }

    function removeItem(key) {
      return storage.delete(String(key));
    }

    function clear() {
      return storage.clear();
    }

    return {
      get length() {
        return storage.size;
      },
      key,
      getItem,
      setItem,
      removeItem,
      clear,      
    };

  }());
</script>
```